# cannot create a partition table on /dev/sdb

Tags: fdisk

when I'm trying to create a partition table on my 8gb sd card, its showing this error:

```
fdisk: unable to read /dev/sdb: Input/output error
```

I have used `sudo fdisk -l` , there the `/dev/sdb` is not listed, what should I do? please help me .

Comment: Make sure that the pendrive you wish to partition is not reserving any other name like /dev/sdc.

Comment: its dev/sdb , showing in gparted partition, but in the terminal command list its not showing.

Comment: Disconnect and connect the drive again. What do the dmesg print?

Comment: sorry , what is dmesg print?

Comment: type 'dmesg | tail' in terminal and paste the output here.

Comment: [ 8486.956376] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 8486.956380] sd 14:0:0:0: [sdb]  
[ 8486.956383] Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
[ 8486.956390] Info fld=0x40
[ 8486.956393] sd 14:0:0:0: [sdb]  
[ 8486.956398] Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error
[ 8486.956403] sd 14:0:0:0: [sdb] CDB: 
[ 8486.956406] Read(10): 28 00 00 00 00 40 00 00 08 00
[ 8486.956422] end_request: critical target error, dev sdb, sector 64
[ 8486.956428] Buffer I/O error on device sdb, logical block 8

Comment: please help me, i want to format the partition table.

Comment: Is the device visible in the list of 'lsusb'. Type it in terminal

Comment: anyhow i managed to display in the list..  here is the p command for my sdb..                                                             Disk /dev/sdb: 7822 MB, 7822376960 bytes
241 heads, 62 sectors/track, 1022 cylinders, total 15278080 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xa13f8044

Comment: Now what should i do for creating a partition table? its 8gb sd card

Comment: The drive is toast; time to get a new one.

Comment: The pendrive/hard-disk whatever it is, is damaged, don't use it and certainly take backup of it's contents if you somehow manage to get it running(Doubtful). Also, edit your main post and post contents of command 'mount' .

Answer (score 3):

As the device is present in the list of 'lsusb', the only option you could try out will be to format the pendrive completely.

But before that, open 'Disk Utility' and check whether the pendrive is present. If present you could format and partition from that application itself.

If the device is not found in 'Disk Utility', you will have to format using the command:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sd(x)
```

where (x) can be b, c, d etc. Care is to be taken as selecting the wrong device can even endup formatting your harddisk.

If your pendrive have a led indicator, it must indicate that the device is busy when the above command is executed.

Comment: but its showing Obytes space in my laptop. although i formatted in disk utility

Comment: Use the command mentioned above

Comment: THis time getting an error while formatting through disk utility.. error creating file system: command-line mkfs.vfat -l -n ............

Comment: and this is my dd command output:  dd: writing to ‘/dev/sdb’: Input/output error
1+0 records in
0+0 records out
0 bytes (0 B) copied, 0.259265 s, 0.0 kB/s

Comment: I have used this command "sudo mkfs.vfat /dev/sdb -I" too. which results: mkfs.vfat 3.0.16 (01 Mar 2013)
mkfs.vfat: failed whilst writing reserved sector

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately an I/O error means that Linux cannot read or write your drive for whatever reason. Usually that means that the drive is broken, but I've heard of instances where it still works with Windows or OS X.