# Cannot create partition table on sd card

Tags: partitioning, kubuntu, gparted, sd-card, fdisk

I cannot create a partition table ( nor msdos, nor GPT ) on my new 64 GB PNY micro sd-card.
 I tried: 
- using GParted ( in Kubuntu 20.04 and in Mint 20.3 ) 
- fdisk in the terminal ( Kubuntu ) 
- diskmanager in Windows 10 
- KDE partition manager in Manjaro (Live).
[image]
As you can see in the picture I get a I/O error. 
I tried another sd-card in the build-in cardreader and that just reads fine. 
I looked at [Unable to create partition in 32GB sd card due to problem in Partition Table?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/946035/unable-to-create-partition-in-32gb-sd-card-due-to-problem-in-partition-table) because it seemed to have a kind of the same problem. And a bunch of other posts such as [cannot create a partition table on /dev/sdb](https://askubuntu.com/questions/423853/cannot-create-a-partition-table-on-dev-sdb), [Cannot save the partition table and format sd card using gparted and fdisk](https://askubuntu.com/questions/899945/cannot-save-the-partition-table-and-format-sd-card-using-gparted-and-fdisk), [Cannot create partition table on SSD](https://askubuntu.com/questions/558459/cannot-create-partition-table-on-ssd) but haven't found a solution yet. Does anybody have an idea how to solve it? ( I don't have an external cardreader, so I can't use another computer.)
I run:
Operating System: Kubuntu 20.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.18.8
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.68.0
Qt Version: 5.12.8
Kernel Version: 5.13.0-44-generic
OS Type: 64-bit
Processors: 8 × Intel® Core™ i7-10510U CPU @ 1.80GHz
Memory: 15,3 GiB
on a HP Envy 17 ce1000n
in tripleboot with Mint 20.3 Una and Windows 10.

Comment: I suspect that your new 64 GB PNY micro sd-card is faulty. You can try according to [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/cant-format-my-usb-drive-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted/933035#933035) to wipe the first mibibyte (overwrite with zeros) with `mkusb`, and format after that with `gparted`. If these operations also fail, you should return the card to the vendor and ask for a replacement.

Comment: I installed mkusb and wiped the cards ( they came in a pack of 2 ). The problem is still there. So I will return the cards. Thanks for your help ( and writing the program !!! Solves my fear of using dd in command line. Great job!! )

Comment: I'm glad I could help you. Good luck :-)